# Ember.js with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, web, ember.js

I can’t find a clear answer to this question anywhere so here it goes. Looking at [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com), it seems like you can build a full fledged application with just JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. My question is, is it advisable to do it that way? I see no examples with PHP integrated into the JavaScript framework so, to me, it seems like an either/or kinda deal. Is that right?

Comment: Ember.js is built by various guys with strong ties to Ruby on Rails. If there's a PHP framework that follows the more important parts of the RoR standards, that should do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> …PHP integrated into the JavaScript framework…

I don't know what kind of answer your are expecting here... 
As PHP is a server-side language, what I do is code my REST APIs on the server side in PHP, an all my application logic is written on Ember.js, and executed on the client.
On another part, the server generates some of the needed handlebars templates, and serves them to the client on the first application load.

Comment: Well that's what I mean. I assumed there would be some sort of REST connection with PHP to ember.js but all the examples I'm finding of the JS framework have the data layer written in javascript as well. I was wondering if they're advocating an all JS application or just JS for the frontend.

Comment: They're intentionally not advocating any toolchain for the back end. Which is sort of helpful (not forcing people to abandon the tools they're used to) but also sort of confusing (not providing examples of how to integrate Ember with various tools).

Comment: Exactly! I think I decided to use the few examples of ember data interacting through REST with my chosen backend. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call the data from PHP and send it to Emberjs, you may need to use JQuery Ajax functions.

For example.

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "POST",
  url: "../model/my_model.php",
  data:{choosen_id: choosen_id,contact_age: contact_age },
    //data:"contact_id_choosen="+ choosen_id,
  }).done(function(data) {

  data_formated = '<div class="formated_data">'+data+'</div>';
  $(".dialog-window").html(data_formated);
    //return result
  }).fail(function(x,s,e) {
    alert(s+": "+e);
    alert('detail button failed!');
    //alert(result);
  });//$.ajax END
```

Above Ajax code sample can insert a correctly formatted PHP data array into the EmberJS.
Hope it helps you to find your way through.